# Double inequality - two or three separate inequalities?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If I have the double inequality
$a\geq b \geq c$, does it mean I have two separate inequalities
\begin{align}
a&\geq b \\
b&\geq c
\end{align}
Or is it three separate inequalities
\begin{align}
a&\geq b \\
b&\geq c \\
a & \geq c
\end{align}
?

Comment: If Anna is taller than Betty, and Betty is taller than Chloe, is Anna taller than Chloe?

Comment: All three expressions are valid. Only convenience or circumstance would affect your choice of usage at any given time.

Answer (score 0):

All three expressions are equivalent. Some times expression like $$\begin{align}
a&\geq b \\
b&\geq c
\end{align}$$ is useful and some times $$\begin{align}
a&\geq b \\
b&\geq c \\
a & \geq c
\end{align}$$
For example in convex optimization when we are going to apply duality any of this two expressions may cause completely different dual problems, one solvable and another not!

Answer (score 0):

When you speak of double inequality, $a\ge b\ge c$ generally implies $a\ge c$, as well as $a\ge b$ and $b\ge c$. This is transitivity of (partial) order: $a\ge b$ and $b\ge c$ imply $a\ge c$. Still, you should check the definition of $\ge$ in your context and whether your $\ge$ indeed satisfies transitivity whenever possible, although this is known to be the case as far as integers, rational numbers, and real numbers with standard $\ge$ (which are primary subjects of precalculus) are concerned, and checking these may sometimes be beyond the scope of precalculus.

Let us have a look at the case of nonnegative rational numbers for slightly nontrivial example. We usually define $a/b\ge c/d$ by $$a\times d-b\times c\ge_{\mathbb{Z}} 0,$$
where $a,b>0,c,d>0$ is some nonnegative integers and $\ge_{\mathbb{Z}}$ is the standard order of integers (e.g. $4\ge_{\mathbb{Z}} 1$, $3\ge_{\mathbb{Z}}-5$). Then, suppose $a/b\ge c/d$ and $c/d\ge e/f$ hold. Then it follows $$a\times d-b\times c\ge 0,\quad c\times f-d\times e\ge 0.$$
Multiplying $f$ to both sides of the first inequality yields
$$a\times d\times f-b\times c\times f\ge 0,$$
while $b$ to the second yields
$$b\times c\times f-b\times d\times e\ge 0.$$
Hence $$a\times d\times f-b\times d\times e=(a\times d\times f-b\times c\times f)+(b\times c\times f-b\times d\times e)\ge 0.$$
This indicates $d\times(a\times f-b\times e)\ge 0$ and thus $a\times f-b\times e$ cannot be negative, as $d>0$. Now we can say that $a/b\ge c/d$ and $c/d\ge e/f$ imply $a/b\ge e/f$. In other words, this $\ge$ satisfies transitivity. Then it is often convenient to compactly write $a/b\ge c/d\ge e/f$ to express such an order.

**Important points twice**: Double inequality $a\ge b\ge c$, generally implies $a\ge c$, in addition to $a\ge b$ and $b\ge c$. When you write it, make sure your $\ge$ satisfies transitivity; otherwise it does not make much sense and is likely to confuse readers.